# Search and then delete depending on whether files contain a string

Tags: file, batch-file, text, delete-file, findstr

I'd like to search through multiple text files in a single directory for a string ('monkey'), if the string exists, then either, depending on what's easiest:

1. rename the matching string - e.g. change monkey monkey1 and save then file and carry on searching/processing

or

2. Delete any file that has the matching string.

Have searched but can't seem to find anything straightforward.

Answer (score 8):

Modifying the contents of a text file is fairly complex using native Windows batch commands, so option 1) is not easy. Though it is easy if you download a 3rd party tool like gnu sed for Windows.

Option 2) is very easy. You can do it on the command line without a batch file. Assuming your current directory is where you want to look for the files:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('findstr /m monkey *.txt') do del "%F"
```

If executed from within a batch file then you need to double up the percents - use `%%F` instead of `%F`.

There are many options to the FINDSTR command, such as /I for case insensitive search, /S to search subdirectories, and /R for primitive regex searches.